# Room not returning duplicates

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-room, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

So I have a room database all set up, everything is fine, so I can make queries and inserts, delete etc no problems, however i've just run into a situation where id like to return entries by their Ids and duplicates should be allowed, however room is removing the duplicates, so for instance I send it a list of ids say <1,2,3,2,3> and it returns items by their ids but only sends me <1,2,3> removing the duplicate entries. The query I'm making is below (btw complete noob at sql)

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE cardId IN(:cardId)")
LiveData<List<Card>> getCardsByIds(List<Integer> cardId);
```

Im using it via a repository I created (just a level of abstraction) and calling this repo from a ViewModel, this ViewModel has a mutable live data integer list containing the ids and using a SwitchMap I get the latest live data. ill include the relevant pieces below

CARD REPO calls my Daos method like this

```
public LiveData<List<Card>> getCardsByIds(List<Integer> cardIds){
    return cardDao.getCardsByIds(cardIds);
}
```

ViewModel calls for them

```
private MutableLiveData<List<Integer>> cardIds;
//** constructor etc
cards = Transformations.switchMap(cardIds, id -> cardRepository.getCardsByIds(id));
```

and through the magic of SwitchMap when the cardIds list updates a new query is made and I observe the ViewModel from my fragment. I've debugged it so I know the list of Ids is correct and has the duplicates Ids, but the returned LiveData list is missing the duplicate Ids. any help?

Comment: Is the `id` the primary key of the database table?

Comment: yes it is the primary key

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:***

> The SQLiteDatabase always presents the results as a Cursor in a table format that resembles that of a SQL database.

Source : [Google Developer Training](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%204/101_c_sqlite_database.html)

Before the results are returned by the query, the results are stored in a table, and if there are rows with duplicate primary keys, they would be omitted by default.

To achieve what you intend, you can execute a query to find single element by id in loop and append the result to a list.

***Updated DAO method:***

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE cardId=:cardId")
LiveData<Card> getCardById(Integer cardId);
```

***Update Repository method:***

```
public LiveData<List<Card>> getCardsByIds(List<Integer> cardIds){
    List list = new ArrayList();
    for(Integer cardId: cardIds){
      list.append(cardDao.getCardById(cardId));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Original Answer:**

If `id` is the primary key of your model, It doesn't allow duplicate data to be entered. Hence while retrieving you might find duplicates missing.

If you have `id` with duplicate, create another attribute for primary key. (use autogenerate if you don't have any primary key attribute)

A primary key is by default UNIQUE and NOT NULL.

Comment: i think youve missed the point i want it to return the same entry twice if ive asked for it]

Comment: i havent tried to insert a model with the same id im trying to get the same entry multiple times if its been asked for multiple times but in the same query, so for instance i have ids<1,2,3> in my database i would like to display <1,2,3,1,2,3> its the same entries i would just like them to display twice, but when i query for it the duplicates are ommitted, which i dont think is right, i think sql in this instance should return . the correct results

Comment: ok many thanks, although your comments on "To achieve what you intend, you can execute a query to find single element by id in loop and append the result to a list." wouldnt work with live data, so maybe your original idea of creating another key/id will work many thanks

Comment: i cant see this referenced anywhere "Before the results are returned by the query, the results are stored in a table, and if there are rows with duplicate primary keys, they would be omitted by default."

Comment: It is what I understood, not stated anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193216/discussion-between-abhi-and-martinseal1987).